# If 1 photon hits 1 atom, will the departing angle be deterministic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, determinism, randomness

Consider a single photon fired towards a single atom.

After interacting with the atom, the photon heads away from the atom (assume no absorption).

Is the angle at which the photon departs deterministic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. Any configuration of atom and photon that is kinematically consistent (i.e. energy momentum conservation) with the initial configuration is a possible state after the interaction.

However not every final state is equally likely to occur and it is indeed possible to compute the probability distribution of the angle through QFT techniques but this is not trivial.